# Google sheets and Rstudio

Tags: r, google-sheets

Is there a way to collect data from googlesheet and make a daily graph from it?

Thank you very much.

A function that let me connect google sheet with Rstudio.

Comment: This will not work this way. To get what you want please go through this: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 1):

`googlesheets4` package let's you access your googlesheets data